# Youtube Upload Widget onApiReady not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I'm attempting to utilize the Youtube Upload Widget to upload videos from a site.  I have the following javascript:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    widget = new YT.UploadWidget('widget', {
        events: {
            onApiReady: function (event) {
                event.target.setVideoTitle($("#title"));
                event.target.setVideoDescription($("#description"));
                event.target.setVideoPrivacy($("#privacy"));
            },
            onProcessingComplete: function(event) {
                document.getElementById('processing').style.display = "none";
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    height: 390,
                    width: 640,
                    videoId: event.data.videoId,
                    modestbranding: 1,
                    rel: 0,
                    events: {}
                });

                $("#updates").slideUp('slow', function() { });
            },
            onUploadSuccess: function(event) {
                alert('Video ID ' + event.data.videoId + ' was uploaded and is currently being processed.');
                widgetVideoId = videoId = event.data.videoId;
                timeout = setTimeout(showProcessing, 1);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The video uploads just fine but onApiReady's function never fires.  I'm not sure what I'm missing, because it looks complete.  Hopefully someone can provide an idea on what I've missed.  It doesn't work in IE9, FF, Chrome, or Safari.  I'd like to be able to update the metadata on the video when it's uploaded.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't fire? I'm guessing one of your event.target statements is failing.

Comment: I went ahead and added an alert statement into the onApiReady's callback function, and it never triggers.  A breakpoint also is never triggered in Firebug or IE's Dev Tools

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors? Did you try removing the other two callbacks?

Comment: No javascript errors in the console.  I tried removing the other two callbacks, but there was no change in the firing of onApiReady.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  It seems that you must use the `<div id="widget"></div>` format for the widget controller instead of the iframe method in order for onApiReady to fire.

Thanks for your assistance Brad.

Answer (score 0):

```
event.target.setVideoTitle($("#title"));
event.target.setVideoDescription($("#description"));
event.target.setVideoPrivacy($("#privacy"));
```

All of these methods require a string parameter, whereas you are passing them a jQuery object.
I believe you mean to use .val()

Comment: That was my bad.  I've gone ahead and changed it, but still no dice at this point.  Thanks for the catch though